# Get a list from a list of list

Tags: list, prolog

Hi I'm fairly new with prolog and have problems figuring out what I'm doing.
My task seems fairly simple. I'd like to retrieve a list from a list of list.

I'd also like to retrieve the Nieme (Nth) element of every list in the list of list to build a list.

1st task example:

```
ListList([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

return only [1,2]

2nd task example:

```
ListList([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], N)  %Where N is the index i want ex:2
```

return only [2,4,6]

Thanks

EDIT: What I got so far:

Still browsing the web. I found nth1 that works for my 1st task. Also something like :

```
match([Elem|_],Num,Num,Elem) :-
    !.
match([_|Tail],Num,Count,MatchedNumber) :-
    Count < Num,
    Count1 is Count+1,
    match(Tail,Num,Count1,MatchedNumber).
```

Still nothing so far for the 2nd task so far. I need to use a double sort of recursion

Comment: A predicate does *not* return anything. It *unifies* a variable...

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I meant like store it in an other argument that I would pass in the function. Something like ListList ([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], List)

Comment: (a) predicates have to start with lowercase; and (b) what have you tried?

Comment: Still browsing the web. I found nth that works for my 1st task. Also something like :

match([Elem|_],Num,Num,Elem) :-
    !.
match([_|Tail],Num,Count,MatchedNumber) :-
    Count < Num,
    Count1 is Count+1,
    match(Tail,Num,Count1,MatchedNumber).

That works well. Still nothing so far for the 2nd task

Comment: Sorry for the bad format. I'll edit the question

Comment: Instead of "browsing the web" to look for an answer, why not crack open a Prolog tutorial or book to learn the Prolog first? :)

Comment: Well that's sorta what I'm doing. I have my prolog open and trying / testing things. You need to browse the web to learn though

Comment: You might want to check out [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/). There are lots of example problems on list processing, with answers, that will help you see how list processing works. You just need some very basic list processing to achieve your goals on these problems.

Comment: I'll look into that right away, thanks

Comment: Your book or manual should tell you how Prolog works. If it doesn't, then you need another book or manual. Prolog works through unification of terms, which is fundamentally different than other languages. A list can be represented as `[H|T]` where `H` is the first element (head) and `T` is the rest of the list (the tail - itself a list). If you unify your list with `[H|_]` (I don't care what the tail is) then `H` will be the first element of the list. If you're not sure what *unfication* is, check your manual, or Google search "prolog unification*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle the first problem. You only need the head of the given list. That's all. A list can be written as `[H|T]` where `H` is the head (or first element) and `T` is the tail (the result of the list, itself a list).

If you have a list, `[a,b,c]` and unify it with `[H|T]`, Prolog will do something interesting. Try this at the Prolog prompt:

```
?- [a,b,c] = [H|T].
```

Observe what you get. Also note that you can do unification in the head of a predicate.

Here's another thing to try. Go into Prolog and enter this:

```
?- [user].
head_tail(L, Head, Tail) :-
     L = [Head | Tail].

foo([H|T], H, T).

Ctrl^D
true.
```

Then try:

```
?- head_tail([a,b,c], H, T).
```

And also try:

```
?- foo([a,b,c], H, T).
```

And see what you get. You can use this to understand how to solve your first problem.

In your second problem, you can also use unification. In this case, though, you're now walking recursively through your list.

```
match([], ...).         % Handle the empty list
match([H|T], ...) :-    % Handle the general case with recursion
    % do something here with H and/or T
    ...
    match(T, ...).
```

You just need to figure out what `...` looks like in each case.